# Invoking systems command in R shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny r script in which I am invoking systems command to generate a bunch of files. But it seems like R shiny server does not run that system command. Is there a way to run systems commands from shiny server?

Comment: are you talking about the function `sys.call()` or something different? Can you please add some code to this to make it an [mcve]?

Comment: yes invoking system call. I got it working now. It was basically some issues with the permission of shiny server directory.

Comment: @nan, please feel free to post an answer and accept it. Better with more details on permission settings.

Comment: can you share how you solved it? i'm facing a similar need

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes out to OP. The problem of inability to use `sys.call` is  connected to  the permission settings of Shiny server directory.